# Value replacement in a file done multiple times

Tags: javascript, php

I have a file with configuration data for the client-side engine written in javascript. I need  to create a configurator that will constantly alter one array of data in the config file using php. Here's the array:

```
var sources = new Array(
    {
    src  : somedata,
    name : "Info",
    ratio: 4/3
    },
    {
    src  : somedata2,
    name : "Тest 1",
    ratio: 16/9
    },
    {
    src  : somedata3,
    name : "Тest 2",
    ratio: 16/9
    }
    );
```

I know i can create a template where i put a placeholder in place of the array, but i don't really want to create another file as there will be many of them. Is there another way of doing it? Will appreciate any advice.

EDIT: To elaborate, I'd have a form that sends a POST request to a php file with data (src, name, ratio), this php file in theory should alter the array in that config file (overwrite it), and the page should reload with new config.

Comment: What code have you tried already in PHP? Your question is not very clear to me.

Comment: Have you considered using a DB table for storing the configuration as well?

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos no, i'm just trying to plan what I'm gonna do and i can't really come up with anything.

Comment: @Havelock I'd love to honestly, but that means the engine that loads config data should be altered and I don't have access to it.